# How do I break in the NSArray with NSString substrings enclosed in quotes

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring

I have a NSSring:

```
NSString *example = @"'example01','example02','example03','example04'";
```

How can I make from this line NSArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *example = [example stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];

NSArray * exampleArr = [example componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Comment: well that was a fast (and correct) answer; +1 to you; and it'll come up with an array that looks like "`'example01'`", "`'example02'`" (i.e. the single quotes WILL remain there).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *commaSeparatedComponents = [example componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSCharacterSet *quotesSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"'"];
for (NSString *component in commaSeparatedComponents) {
    NSString *correctlyTrimmedComponent = [component stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:quotesSet]; // only remove 's at the edges
    // ... do something with each component; maybe add to a mutable array ...
}
```

This has the advantage over the other answer to not remove quotes that exist inside the values, but it doesn't do anything to actually solve quotes escaping that might have been necessary inside the data, and so on. It still misbehaves with some strings, but it misbehaves for fewer cases because it is less flippant about which quotes it removes.

If this is anything above and beyond a string in that exact format, you will probably need a parser for this sort of string that can handle the semantics of how the quotes are escaped, gracefully handles garbage, etc.